# Where can I access my top network posts from Stack Overflow?

Tags: support, profile-page

In the old design, there was a "Top Network Posts" section down my user page. In the new design, the "Top Network Posts" section only shows for other users, not for me. Is it somewhere I am not seeing or was it removed?

Comment: You mean [this](https://stackexchange.com/users/8908789/wais-kamal?tab=top)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/users/current/?tab=profile), do you not see this section?

[image]

Comment: Oooh I didn't even think of going to the profile tab. Thanks a lot!